# Style all instances of class except selected in CSS

Tags: html, css

Given an application with multiple instances of a class *.element*, I want something like this:

```
.element:hover rest {
    opacity: 0.5
}
```

Where "rest" refers to every other instance of .element except the one hovered. The desired functionality for the code above would be all instances of .element becoming opaque, while the hovered element remains without style.

Is this possible without using javascript?

Comment: Probably can't as there is no previous sibling selector, please post how markup looks like.

Comment: Yes, you would solve this by inverting your styles and apply opacity to `.element` and then on `element:hover` you would remove the opacity.

Comment: Removing the opacity on element:hover would be fundamentally different. .element instances would be opaque by default - I only want them to turn opaque if another instance is hovered.

Comment: What markup would you like me to post?

Comment: There is no selector equivalent to the one you are wanting. Depending on your HTML structure, you may be able to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ftek5mhs/1/ . Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends entirely on how your HTML is structured.

If the elements share a common ancestor that could be used as the trigger for the opacity change, you could possibly achieve the result that you are looking for.

```css
.parent:hover .child {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.parent .child:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user7548189 I think this is what you are looking for. This method uses the entire parent element and applies the CSS to that. Then depending on what child element you hover on the CSS overrides those styles.